# Git pane in Rstudio unchangeble from C:\Users\my_user_name

Tags: git, rstudio

When creating a project with Git within Rstudio, the git pane shows all files and folders available in C:\Users\my_user_name.

I haven't found a way to change the directory showed in the git pane.
I have this problem despite:
- Creating a project (with Git) to the specific folder that interests me.
- Having the specific folder that interest me as working directory in R and in the Git shell.

Comment: Do you have an `.Rproj` project file? Have you opened RStudio by selecting that file?

Comment: Yes. I have a .Rproj file in the directory that interests me. When I open the project with Rstudio, I still get the C:\Users\my_user_name in my git pane.